# How did Master Jailer attack Supergirl in Episode 14?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

In Season 1 Episode 14, when the detective reveals himself as the Master Jailer, he shoots Alex and then he points some kind of light at Supergirl. Then we see Supergirl waking up in that jail.

How did he so easily knock her out?

Comment: I suppose he just had good alien technology in his suit.

Comment: High powered red sun radiation beam?

Comment: Deus ex flashlight.